# How to add items to my array with ForEach-Object

Tags: xml, powershell

I am trying to export specific request properties from a CRM system to build custom reports in excel. As I don't have direct access to it's sql server I'm using the API.
The API response can be XML or JSON.

My firs query returns around 13 requests and their basic details based on a view I set up in the CRM then I need to use a second query to get the additional fields for each request. So I tried to create an array where I can store all the fields I need then can export it to a single csv later.

However when I try to add new items to my array with ForEach-Object it just overwrites the same item over and over.

Also at my second Invoke-RestMethod for the -Uri I'm supposed to use the "current" request number but I'm not sure how to properly reference that.

```
$inputdata = @"
{
    "operation": {
        "details": {
            "from": "0",
            "limit": "200",
            "filterby": "9304_MyView"
        }
    }
}
"@

$Params = @{OPERATION_NAME='GET_REQUESTS';INPUT_DATA=$inputdata;TECHNICIAN_KEY='mykey';format='json'}
$Response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri http://myserver/request -Method Post -Body $Params
$RequestNumber = $Response.operation.details.WORKORDERID
$current = $RequestNumber[0]

$array = @()
ForEach-Object -InputObject $RequestNumber {
$Parameter = @{OPERATION_NAME='GET_REQUEST';TECHNICIAN_KEY='mykey'}
$data = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri http://myserver/request/$current -Method GET -Body $Parameter

$object = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
$object | Add-Member -Name 'RequestNumber' -MemberType NoteProperty -Value $data.API.response.operation.Details.parameter.value[0]
$object | Add-Member -Name 'Subject' -MemberType NoteProperty -Value $data.API.response.operation.Details.parameter.value[12] 
$array += @($object)
    }
```

Can somebody please explain what am I doing wrong?
*Sorry English is not my first language but I hope it makes some sense.

**Solution based on  Moerwald's suggestion**

I learned that using the -InputObject parameter treated my $RequestNumber as a single object and passed along all the "ticket number" so I moved the array creation above the $RequestNumber and then piped the $RequestNumber to ForEach-Object.

```
$inputdata = @"
{
    "operation": {
        "details": {
            "from": "0",
            "limit": "200",
            "filterby": "9304_MyView"
        }
    }
}
"@

$Params = @{OPERATION_NAME='GET_REQUESTS';INPUT_DATA=$inputdata;TECHNICIAN_KEY='mykey';format='json'}
$Response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri http://myserver/request -Method Post -Body $Params
$array = @()
$RequestNumber = $Response.operation.details.WORKORDERID |

ForEach-Object {
    $Parameter = @{OPERATION_NAME='GET_REQUEST';TECHNICIAN_KEY='mykey'}
    $data = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri http://myserver/request/$_ -Method GET -Body $Parameter

    $object = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
    $object | Add-Member -Name 'RequestNumber' -MemberType NoteProperty -Value $data.API.response.operation.Details.parameter.value[0]
    $object | Add-Member -Name 'Subject' -MemberType NoteProperty -Value $data.API.response.operation.Details.parameter.value[12] 
    $array += $object
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$current` always points to `$RequestNumber[0]` therefore `$data` always contains the same data.

```
$inputdata = @"
{
    "operation": {
        "details": {
            "from": "0",
            "limit": "200",
            "filterby": "9304_MyView"
        }
    }
}
"@

$Params = @{OPERATION_NAME='GET_REQUESTS';INPUT_DATA=$inputdata;    TECHNICIAN_KEY='mykey';format='json'}
$Response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri http://myserver/request -Method Post -Body $Params
$RequestNumber = $Response.operation.details.WORKORDERID

$array = @()
ForEach-Object -InputObject $RequestNumber {
    $Parameter = @{OPERATION_NAME='GET_REQUEST';TECHNICIAN_KEY='mykey'}
    $data = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri http://myserver/request/$_ -Method GET -Body $Parameter

    $object = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
    $object | Add-Member -Name 'RequestNumber' -MemberType NoteProperty -Value     $data.API.response.operation.Details.parameter.value[0]
    $object | Add-Member -Name 'Subject' -MemberType NoteProperty -Value    $data.API.response.operation.Details.parameter.value[12] 
    $array += $object
}
```

Tried to fix the code, see above. I removed `$current`, and using the actual object in the pipeline (=`$_`, [about_pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipelines?view=powershell-6)) for `Invoke-RestMethod`. I also changed `$array += @($object)` to `$array += $object`, since you want to add an object to the array and not a new array to the array (which is what the `@()` [array sub-expression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays?view=powershell-6) stands for).

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You're $array is getting reset each time by constructing a new array. The following code just loops through numbers for simplicity. Note: += constructs the array from scratch so performance might be an issue (see [FoxDeploy](https://foxdeploy.com/2016/03/23/coding-for-speed/)'s detailed answer for the reason why) .

```
$array = @()


0..20 | ForEach-Object { 

    $object = $_
    # Use += for adding to an array
    $array += $object
}

Write $array
```

A faster way of doing the same operation is to use the .Net ArrayList. Credit to [FoxDeploy](https://foxdeploy.com/2016/03/23/coding-for-speed/) for this answer.

```
$array = new-object System.Collections.ArrayList

0..20 | ForEach-Object { 

    $object = $_
    # Call the Method Add here
    $array.Add($object)
}

Write $array
```

Comment: Or just use
`$array = 0..20 | ForEach-Object { }`